# Postgres - Where condition on nested joins table not working

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have 3 tables:
**order_items, invoice_items and invoices**

In order_items model:

```
has_many :invoice_items
```

P.S an order_item may or may not have any invoice items associated with it

In Invoices model:

```
has_many :invoice_items
```

In InvoiceItem model

```
belongs_to :order_item
belongs_to :invoice
```

order_items table has `booked_quantity` and `cancelled_quantity` fields in it

invoices table has `state` field in it. `state` can be cancelled or approved

invoice_items table has `quantity` field in it.

An order item is considered to be invoiceable when the following condition holds:

> (booked_quantity - cancelled_quantity - SUM(invoice_items.quantity where associated invoice is not cancelled)) > 0

I am trying to fetch all the order items which are invoiceable using single sql query. Here are the two solutions that i tried:

**Solution 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM order_items
       LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice_items ON invoice_items.order_item_id = order_items.id
       INNER JOIN invoices ON invoices.id = invoice_items.invoice_id
       WHERE invoices.state != 'cancelled'
       GROUP BY order_items.id
       HAVING ((booked_quantity - cancelled_quantity - COALESCE(SUM(invoice_items.quantity))) > 0)
       ORDER BY order_items.id ASC
```

**Solution 2:**

```
(
  WITH ii_ord_items AS
  (
    SELECT invoice_items.order_item_id, COALESCE(SUM(invoice_items.quantity), 0) AS uncancelled_invoiced_quantity from order_items
    LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice_items ON invoice_items.order_item_id = order_items.id
    INNER JOIN invoices ON invoices.id = invoice_items.invoice_id
    WHERE invoices.state != 'cancelled'
    GROUP BY invoice_items.order_item_id
  )
  SELECT order_items.* FROM order_items
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ii_oitems ON order_items.id = ii_oitems.order_item_id
  WHERE ( ii_ord_items.uncancelled_invoiced_quantity < (order_items.booked_quantity - order_items.cancelled_quantity))
) AS order_items
```

Both of them are working fine when invoiced is not in cancelled state. But in case when invoice is cancelled both of them are giving incorrect results. They seem to be considering cancelled invoices quantity as well. So i guess there's some problem with the where condition but i couldn't figure out what's the issue exactly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

**Sample Data:**

**order_items table**

```
id      booked_quantity   cancelled_quantity
1          10                    2
```

**invoices table**

```
id      state
1       cancelled
```

**invoice_items table**

```
id      invoice_id    order_item_id     quantity
1           1              1               8
```

**Expected Result:** If i try to fetch all the order items for which invoice_items can be generated should include order_item with id 1 as well as invoice is currently cancelled. If the invoice state would have been anything other than "cancelled" then order_item with id 1 should not be present in the result.

Comment: In `InvoiceItem`, you have `belongs_to :invoice_item`. Is that a typo?

Comment: yes. will fix this.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help me understand this problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the question to include sample data as well as results. Kindly check. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are stuck at this/similar problem to this..the idea is only those invoice items should be joined where invoice state is cancelled. If we have two separate join statements then invoice items will get joined even though invoice state is cancelled. So basically, joining of invoice items should have an inner query to filter out only concerned invoice items.

Here's the final solution that i implemented:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT oi.*
  FROM order_items oi
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
         (SELECT ii.* from invoice_items ii
         INNER JOIN invoices inv
         ON inv.id = ii.invoice_id AND inv.state != 'cancelled') uncancelled_ii
         ON uncancelled_ii.order_item_id = oi.id
  GROUP BY oi.id
  HAVING (booked_quantity - cancelled_quantity - COALESCE(SUM(uncancelled_ii.quantity), 0)) > 0
  ORDER BY oi.id ASC
```